# How to align Qcomboboxes in different Qlayouts?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working in a QT project. There are two Widgets (`QFormLayout`) inside a `QVBoxLayout` (just a simple box). Each `QFormLayout` contains rows with two columns: a label and a `Qcombobox`, and each `QFormLayout` can have one or more rows. The first `QFormLayout` can be added or not, so this is the reason to have two `QFormLayout` instead a single one. Also, it is important to mention that each widget are created/defined in different classes. So, unfortunately I can't change the current design.

First widget

```
auto settings = new QFormLayout(this);
auto labelName= new QLabel("Some text");
auto combo1 = new QComboBox(this);
settings->addRow(labelName, combo1);
```

Second widget. In this example the second widget have two rows perfectly aligned.

```
auto options = new QFormLayout(this);
auto labelName= new QLabel("Some text");
auto combo2 = new QComboBox(this);
options ->addRow(labelName, combo2);
```

As you can imagine I'm getting the following result:

[image]

there is a way to align and keep the same size of the combobox that are in different widgets?. Maybe align the combobox to the right side could help. I'm trying the following but the result is not good (the combobox width is to small).

```
settings->setAlignment(combo1, Qt::AlignRight);
```

Comment: Can't you have the 2 "blocks" in the same `QFormLayout`?

Comment: Hi @Jarod42, no, unfortunately I can't do this